# setState() and its async nature is not my friend... what can I do?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm aware that my code is terrible and awful, but am struggling here and would appreciate some help. Basically, I'm trying to create a form, where after the button at the bottom is clicked, it will display the information on state. I've tried doing this via a ternary - where if this.state.display is true, it will show as true, and if false, it will show the form.

I believe the problem would have to do with the asynchronous nature of setState. Because setState is slow, this.state.display never truly gets set to true, and therefore the terniary never really gets to execute properly. I just don't know how I would fix this. I've played with shouldComponentUpdate and componentWillUpdate, but it's not been very helpful.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm a newb and recognize that this is far from quality code. Would just love for someone's gentle guidance. Thanks.

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    display: false,
    firstName : "",
    lastName : "",
    phone : null,
    email : "",
    };


  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    if (this.state.display) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}


  render() {




return (
  { this.state.display ? 
   <div>
     <h1>{this.state.firstName}</h1>
     <h1>{this.state.lastName}</h1>
     <h1>{this.state.phone}</h1>
     <h1>{this.state.email}</h1>
   </div> : 

  <div className="header">

  <h1>Greetings!</h1>
  </div>
    <div className="inputform">
      <input placeholder="First Name" onChange={(e) => {this.setState({firstName: e.target.value})}} />
      <input placeholder="Last Name" onChange={(e) => {this.setState({lastName:e.target.value})}} />
      <input placeholder="Phone Number" onChange={(e) => {this.setState({phone:e.target.value})}} />
      <input placeholder="Email Address" onChange={(e) => {this.setState({email:e.target.value})}} />


      <button onClick={this.setState({display: true})}>Submit</button>
    </div>







  }



 ); 
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<Application />
  , document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Using `this.setState` inside your `button` click handler should repeatedly fire off and grind your browser to a halt and create repeated console warnings. I agree with the other answers, but I'm just curious if that is what is happening.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working version of your class:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      display: false,
      firstName : "",
      lastName : "",
      phone : null,
      email : "",
    };
  }
  _renderForm() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="header">
          <h1>Greetings!</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="inputform">
          <input placeholder="First Name" onChange={(e) => {this.setState({firstName: e.target.value})}} />
          <input placeholder="Last Name" onChange={(e) => {this.setState({lastName:e.target.value})}} />
          <input placeholder="Phone Number" onChange={(e) => {this.setState({phone:e.target.value})}} />
          <input placeholder="Email Address" onChange={(e) => {this.setState({email:e.target.value})}} />
          <button onClick={ () => this.setState({ display: true }) }>Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  _renderData() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.firstName}</h1>
        <h1>{this.state.lastName}</h1>
        <h1>{this.state.phone}</h1>
        <h1>{this.state.email}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
  render() {
    return this.state.display ? this._renderData() : this._renderForm();
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

The main problem was that you were calling `setState` immediately during render. While you should pass a function that calls it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a functin to `onClick` handler of `button`. Preferably like this

```
handler = () => {
  this.setState({display: true})
}
render(){
    <button onClick={this.handler}>Submit</button>
}
```